# Show who comment is in reply to (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Threaded comments in wordpress are great, they give you a sort of easy visual tree of discussion to see who's say what to whom.

I was wondering if it would be possible to show replies to comments like:-
'This comment is in reply to (name of person it's in reply to along with the permalink to that comments #, since all comments are given an id of their number on the page, which would easily jump you back up to exactly which comment it was)?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

http://bavotasan.com/2009/how-to-add-nested-comments-to-your-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Nope, I already have quite a nice system of threaded/nested comments set up.
The problem is it gets a bit confusing after you get 3 replies to one comment then someone else replies to that original comment too, you don't quite know visually who's replying to who.

What I'd like to do is have a function (as described above) that actually shows IN the comment who it's directed at.
Like 'In reply to' then a link to the comment.